# iTunes File Sharing - Showing Document Folder Contents

Tags: ios, file-sharing

One of my requirement is to make the user able to move-in files from desktop to my application via (iTunes File Sharing Option). Further, in one of the screen, I will list the files available in the Documents's Folder in table from which the user can select the files to be processed further.

I have implemented and it is working as expected. 
But , i just want to confirm, whether we can have such screen in our application where the **contents of the Documents folder** are being displayed to the user ?

Because, I have read the below link (Section : File-Sharing Support) from Apple about Document Folder, which says that we should never present the user with the contents of the Document Folder.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html

I want to know will the apple reject my application if I submit the app with the above mentioned thing implemented ?

OR what are the ways available to achieve this (Making the user to select file from Document Folder) ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole quote from the docs you reference is (emphasis mine):

> Applications that support file sharing **should** be able to recognize when files have been added to the Documents directory and respond appropriately. For example, your application might make the contents of any new files available from its interface. You **should** never present the user with the list of files in this directory and ask them to decide what to do with those files.

Apple is stating that your app **should** (not must) deal with files being added to Documents, via iTunes, without presenting a list of files to the user. That's the goal but I doubt Apple will reject an app just for showing a file list in the app. Check the App Review Guidelines.

Having said that, there should be no reason to show a list to the user. If the user adds a file via iTunes file sharing then that indicates that the user wants the file to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The guidance is to encapsulate files.

"For example, your application might make the contents of any new files available from its interface. You should never present the user with the list of files in this directory and ask them to decide what to do with those files."