# Integrating iTunes File Sharing

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, file-sharing

I want to be able to list iTunes File Sharing contents in a list, but all the tutorials I've found aren't helpful at all.  They're either extremely vague, only explain how to **enable** it, or are for specific files.

What I really need is how to have my UITableViewController display files in the Directory folder.  I'm in the same boat as this question [iTunes File Sharing - Showing Document Folder Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239748/itunes-file-sharing-showing-document-folder-contents), sort of, but I just need to learn how to actually implement it.

So how do I link my application directory to my UITableViewController?

If anyone can help, that would be awesome of you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've learned a good place to start is the sample code DocInteraction.  It demonstrates "kqueue" kernel event notifications, to monitor the contents of the Documents folder and present them in a `TableViewController`.

Technically not an answer, but my question is no longer (how should I say this?) relevant, active, what have you.